# Apache htaccess if else for react and node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, apache, .htaccess, cpanel

Im trying to deploy a Node backend and a React frontend on a Cpanel.

I have the following htaccess under public_html:

```
# NODE 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/index.*
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:3500/ [P,L]
  RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:3500/ [P,L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:3500/$1 [P,L] 
</IfModule>
 
# REACT
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

If I leave only the node one, the apis work, but the frontend not.
If I leave only the react one, the frontend work, but when I request any api Insomnia returns me the HTML of the frontend.

If I leave the 2, the API works but when I enter on the browser I get an "Unauthorized" message - so its pointing to the backend.

So, is there a way of using the node htaccess configuration only for the /api requests?

Thanks!